# How to set Bluefish as a default editor in FileZilla

Tags: filezilla, bluefish

How to use bluefish as a default editor in filezilla(ubuntu operating system). please give me solution.

thank you

Comment: can you please give me a link to the filezilla, the only filezilla i know is an ftp client..

Answer (score 2):

In the Filezilla FTP client, go to settings. Scroll down until you hit "File Editing" and select "Use Custom Editor:"

You can either browse to the Bluefish exeutable inside of usr/bin/, but the file path that should work (if you have it installed) is /usr/bin/bluefish

I'm relatively inexperienced, and was pleasantly surprised to discover that this /usr/bin/ folder is where most executables of installed programs are located.

Yay for learning new things!

Answer (score 0):

In Filezilla go to:

> *Edit* > *Preferences* > *File Editing*

Then go to:

> *File Editing*  >  *File type associations*

and uncheck *Inherit System's file type associations*

In the Custom filetype associations dialog box type:

> html "/usr/bin/bluefish" -open
>
> shtml "/usr/bin/bluefish" -open
>
> php "/usr/bin/bluefish" -open

(or any other file extensions you want to edit with Bluefish)